# overflow: auto caused by line-height (bug?)

Tags: css

got the following code:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh:
}
.background_overlay {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0.95;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

.box_overlay {
  border: 1.5px solid #000000;
  width: calc(100vw - 6vw);
  height: calc(100vh - 6vw);
  margin: 3vw;
  float: left;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.text_overlay {
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 60%;
  max-height: 60%;
  margin: 0 20%;
  overflow: auto;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 2.2rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  z-index: 4;
  height: auto;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text_overlay">
    <h3>Headline h3</h3>
    <p> Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum v Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem I</p>
  </div>
  <div class="background_overlay"></div>
  <div class="box_overlay"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see I use `overflow: auto;` on the `.text-overlay` because in some cases the text is too long for the box and I think this is the best solution so far for me.

The problem: Even if there is no overflow, you can scroll inside the `.text-overlay` a little bit, so the scrollbar appears.

I found out this is caused by the `line-height` of the `h3`

When I disable it the overflow is gone.

In this screenshot, you can see that the `line-height` of the `h3` makes the element a little bit bigger so it overflows.

[image: overflow: auto disabled and .text-overlay focused in browser to display the height difference]`overflow: auto` disabled and `.text-overlay` focused in browser to display the height difference

So my goal here is to have no scrollbar if it's not needed like it should in my example (run snippet in fullscreen and scroll the text area and a scrollbar will show up).

Comment: So what's your problem?

Comment: Well, sorry I want the scrollbar to not appear, because there is no real overflow

Comment: I didn't clearly understand your problem...

Comment: Just modify/adjust the line-height a bit, for example instead of `2.2rem` try `2.15` or similar.

Comment: Why don't you use overflow: hidden or unset?

Comment: @George because then If there is a longer text that would really overflow it would cut off or overflows my box

Comment: Increase max-height of your text_overlay div a little. Such as 65%.

Comment: @George That would just fix my issue for this exact example. If one line is added there could be the same problem.